# Predicting an output once we are done with training our neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a dataset with 5 columns, I am feeding in first 3 columns as my Inputs and the other 2 columns as my outputs. I have successfully executed the program but i am not sure how to test the model by giving my own values as input and getting a predicted output from the model.

Can anyone please help me, How can I actually test the model with my own value after training is done ? I am using Tensorflow in Python..I am able to display accuracy of testing,but How do I actually predict with value if I pass some random input(here,I need to pass 3 input values to get 2 output values)

Here,is my code:

```
# Implementation of a simple MLP network with one hidden layer. Tested on the iris data set.
# Requires: numpy, sklearn>=0.18.1, tensorflow>=1.0

# NOTE: In order to make the code simple, we rewrite x * W_1 + b_1 = x' * W_1'
# where x' = [x | 1] and W_1' is the matrix W_1 appended with a new row with elements b_1's.
# Similarly, for h * W_2 + b_2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

RANDOM_SEED = 1000
tf.set_random_seed(RANDOM_SEED)


def init_weights(shape):
    """ Weight initialization """
    weights = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(weights)

def forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2):
    """
    Forward-propagation.
    IMPORTANT: yhat is not softmax since TensorFlow's softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() does that internally.
    """
    h    = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))  # The \sigma function
    yhat = tf.matmul(h, w_2)  # The \varphi function
    return yhat

def get_iris_data():
    """ Read the iris data set and split them into training and test sets """
    df = pd.read_csv("H:\MiniThessis\Sample.csv")
    train_X = np.array(df[df.columns[0:3]])
    train_Y = np.array(df[df.columns[3:]])
    print(train_X)

    # Convert into one-hot vectors
    #num_labels = len(np.unique(train_Y))
    #all_Y = np.eye(num_labels)[train_Y]  # One liner trick!
    #print()
    return train_test_split(train_X, train_Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

def main():
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_iris_data()

    # Layer's sizes
    x_size = train_X.shape[1]   # Number of input nodes: 4 features and 1 bias
    h_size = 256                # Number of hidden nodes
    y_size = train_y.shape[1]   # Number of outcomes (3 iris flowers)

    # Symbols
    X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, x_size])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, y_size])

    # Weight initializations
    w_1 = init_weights((x_size, h_size))
    w_2 = init_weights((h_size, y_size))

    # Forward propagation
    yhat    = forwardprop(X, w_1, w_2)
    predict = tf.argmax(yhat, axis=1)

    # Backward propagation
    cost    = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=yhat))
    updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    # Run SGD
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(3):
        # Train with each example
        for i in range(len(train_X)):
            sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X[i: i + 1], y: train_y[i: i + 1]})

        train_accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(train_y, axis=1) == sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y}))
        test_accuracy  = np.mean(np.argmax(test_y, axis=1) ==sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y}))

        print("Epoch = %d, train accuracy = %.2f%%, test accuracy = %.2f%%"
              % (epoch + 1, 100. * train_accuracy, 100. * test_accuracy))


    correct_Prediction = tf.equal((tf.arg_max(predict,1)),(tf.arg_max(y,1)))
    best = sess.run([predict], feed_dict={X: np.array([[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]])})
    #print(correct_Prediction)
    print(best)


    sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As of now,I am using this line at the end of my code and trying to print my output :  best = sess.run([predict], feed_dict={X: np.array([[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]])}) ; print(best)

Comment: You should provide more code so that we can help...

Comment: Unofrtunately,the code is longer than 540 characters :(..Can you please let me know your email Id,so that I can send u my code as well as the test data there?

Comment: @SriHarsha remove unnecessary lines and publish your code. The only relevant part.

Comment: for epoch in range(3): for i in range(len(train_X)):sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X[i: i + 1], y: train_y[i: i + 1]});  train_accuracy = np.mean(np.argmax(train_y, axis=1) == sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y})) ; test_accuracy  = np.mean(np.argmax(test_y, axis=1) ==sess.run(predict, feed_dict={X: test_X, y: test_y})); best = sess.run([predict], feed_dict={X: np.array([[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]])}); print(best)..Here best is my output(2 output values)

Comment: I just want to pass 3 input values and get 2 output values ...Can you please explain me the tensorflow code,which I need to write for achieveing this?As of now I am writing it as best = sess.run([predict], feed_dict={X: np.array([[20.14, 46.93, 1014.66]])})..But this is not working

Comment: Hello Evryone,I just edited my post and now have even included my code in my post..Looking forward for reply! Thanks